# Query of a subquery in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to do a query from another query, but Django said: 'Caught DatabaseError while rendering: subquery returns more than 1 row.' I'm using PostGis.

my model

```
class Place(models.Model):    
    coordinate = models.PointField()

class TranslatedPlace(models.Model):
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place)
```

my view

```
  near_coordinates = Place.objects.filter(coordinate__distance_lte=(place_obj.coordinate, D(km=100)))
  near_places = TranslatedPlace.objects.filter(place=near_coordinates)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you'll want to use [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) to filter the second queryset

```
near_coordinates = Place.objects.filter(coordinate__distance_lte=(place_obj.coordinate, D(km=100)))
near_places = TranslatedPlace.objects.filter(place__in=near_coordinates)
```

Answer (score 3):

If `Place.objects.filter(coordinate__distance_lte=(place_obj.coordinate, D(km=100)))` is SUPPOSED to return multiple objects, you might be able to use `near_places = TranslatedPlace.objects.filter(place__in=near_coordinates)` note the __in for the place field. If you are only supposed to get one and there IS only one, you could do a `.get()` instead of `.filter()`. If there is more than one in the database, but you only want to get one, you could `.filter(...)[0]` to get the first one. Also, you could `.filter(...).order_by('sort_field')[0]` if you want to get the first one based on some sorting.