# In a Django subquery, can I reference the "parent" query?

Tags: subquery, where-clause, django-orm

It's simple to create subqueries in Django ORM (just use a `QuerySet` as part of another query), but is it possible for that subquery to reference fields in the "parent" (outer, main) query?

For a full example of what I'm trying to achieve, see this working [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8b395/13). I broke it down into two questions ([other one here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15453662/520779)). In this case, I have a model `Whole` that represents a value that must be reached. Several `Part`s contribute to it with a (calculated) value of their own. I want to retrieve all the `Whole`s which has **not** been completed yet (i.e. the `total_value` is different from the sum of individual values).

```
select w.*
  from whole w
  where w.total_value != (
    select sum(value expression)
      from part p
      where p.whole_id = w.id
      group by p.whole_id
  );
```

I don't know how (or if it's even possible) to do this using Django ORM. I've seen [many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8556387/520779) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8217576/520779) of subqueries using `__in` (and could confirm by `print qs.query` that the result is indeed ran as a single query), but only when both queries are independent of each other. Here, the subquery is constrained by a field in the parent query (`w.id`). I thought of using `F()`, `Q()`, or even `extra`, but can't quite figure out what to do...

Here's a SSCCE, in case anyone want to experiment with it: [Download](https://marcelogibson.com/stackoverflow/aggregate_subquery.zip) or [Browse](https://marcelogibson.com/stackoverflow/sscce/). It has the same models and data as the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8b395/13) linked above.

---

**Update:** for my particular case, I found out there's no need to do a subquery, I can just use `group by` and `having` (as [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8b395/18) shows):

```
q = Q(part__isnull=True) | ~Q(partial=F('total_value'))
qs = Whole.objects.annotate(partial=Sum(...)).filter(q).distinct()

# And if total_value can be zero:
qs = qs.exclude(part__isnull=True, total_value=0)
```

The general case for subqueries is still unsolved though (short of using some raw SQL, as [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15483656/520779) shows).

Comment: Full support for correlated subqueries is available in Django (as of Django 1.11), including references to the outer query. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Answer (score 2):

The solution I devised with the least raw SQL uses `extra` and `where`:

- First create the inner query; use `extra` to specify a custom `where` component, comparing the restricted field to the one in the outer query, **as it will appear there** (might need to hardcode the table name/alias):

  ```
  qs1 = Part.objects.extra(where=['whole_id = "applabel_whole"."id"'])...
  ```

  Then make the remaining operations on it (in this case, using `values` and `annotate` for grouping, aggregation and return of a single field).
- Then include the generated SQL of the inner query (using `.query`) in the outer query, also using `extra` and `where`:

  ```
  qs = Whole.objects.extra(where=['total_value != ({})'.format(qs1.query)])
  ```

The code fragment in the `extra` calls might not be portable (ex.: some backends use `!=`, others use `<>`, the correct way of quoting table names might vary, etc), but the rest of the inner query shall be (since it was generated by the ORM).

The resulting query corresponds to what I'm looking for (except for the aggregation part, which is covered in [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15453662/520779)). SQL formatted for readability:

```
>>> qs1 = Part.objects.extra(
        where=['whole_id = "aggregation_subquery_whole"."id"']
    ).values('whole_id').annotate(sum=Sum('before__value')).values('sum')

>>> qs = Whole.objects.extra(where=['total_value != ({})'.format(qs1.query)])

>>> print qs.query

SELECT "aggregation_subquery_whole"."id",
       "aggregation_subquery_whole"."total_value" 
FROM "aggregation_subquery_whole"
WHERE total_value != (
    SELECT SUM("aggregation_subquery_sequence"."value") AS "sum"
    FROM "aggregation_subquery_part"
        LEFT OUTER JOIN "aggregation_subquery_sequence" ON
           ("aggregation_subquery_part"."before_id" =
            "aggregation_subquery_sequence"."id") 
    WHERE whole_id = "aggregation_subquery_whole"."id"
    GROUP BY "aggregation_subquery_part"."whole_id"
)
```